# Regex to catch section between 2 quotations

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp, quotations

I can't seem to get my regex right when trying to catch the phrase in between the quotations. E.g. in bold (NOTE: that the input is has strings before and after):

> "I can quite understand your thinking so." **I said.** "Of course, in
>   your position of unofficial adviser and helper to everybody who is
>   absolutely puzzled, throughout three continents, you are brought in
>   contact with all that is strange and bizarre. But here"
>
> "Of course, in your position of unofficial adviser and helper to
>   everybody who is absolutely puzzled, throughout three continents, you
>   are brought in contact with all that is strange and bizarre. But
>   here"**--I picked up the morning paper from the ground--**"let us put
>   it to a practical test. Here is the first heading upon which I come.
>   'A husband's cruelty to his wife.' There is half a column of print,
>   but I know without reading it that it is all perfectly familiar to me.
>   There is, of course, the other woman, the drink, the push, the blow,
>   the bruise, the sympathetic sister or landlady. The crudest of writers
>   could invent nothing more crude."

I've tried to get the the text before and after the quotes but i can't get to the desired output. There must be some way to group the regex up such that **i can catch the string in between the quotes and also the surrounding two quotes**.

Tried:

```
import re

def get_quotes(paragraph):
    quote_rx = r'''([""])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1'''
    return [i.group(0) for i in \
           re.finditer(quote_rx, paragraph, re.S)]

def get_said(paragraph, quote):
    quote_start = paragraph.index(quote)
    quote_end = quote_start + len(quote)
    before = paragraph[:quote_start]
    after = paragraph[quote_end:]
    return before, after


paragraphs = ['''I smiled and shook my head. "I can quite understand your thinking so." I said. "Of course, in your position of unofficial adviser and helper to everybody who is absolutely puzzled, throughout three continents, you are brought in contact with all that is strange and bizarre. But here"--I picked up the morning paper from the ground--"let us put it to a practical test. Here is the first heading upon which I come. 'A husband's cruelty to his wife.' There is half a column of print, but I know without reading it that it is all perfectly familiar to me. There is, of course, the other woman, the drink, the push, the blow, the bruise, the sympathetic sister or landlady. The crudest of writers could invent nothing more crude."''', 
'''Such was the remarkable narrative to which I listened on that April evening -- a narrative which would have been utterly incredible to me had it not been confirmed by the actual sight of the tall, spare figure and the keen, eager face, which I had never thought to see again. In some manner he had learned of my own sad bereavement, and his sympathy was shown in his manner rather than in his words. "Work is the best antidote to sorrow, my dear Watson," said he, "and I have a piece of work for us both to-night which, if we can bring it to a successful conclusion, will in itself justify a man's life on this planet." In vain I begged him to tell me more. "You will hear and see enough before morning," he answered. "We have three years of the past to discuss. Let that suffice until half-past nine, when we start upon the notable adventure of the empty house."''']

for p in paragraphs:
    saids = set()
    for i in get_quotes(p):
        b,a = get_said(p,i)
        print b
        print a
        print
```

Desired output:

```
in-btw: I said.
quotes: ["I can quite understand your thinking so.","Of course, in your position of unofficial adviser and helper to everybody who is absolutely puzzled, throughout three continents, you are brought in contact with all that is strange and bizarre. But here"]
section: "I can quite understand your thinking so." **I said.** "Of course, in your position of unofficial adviser and helper to everybody who is absolutely puzzled, throughout three continents, you are brought in contact with all that is strange and bizarre. But here"


in-btw: --I picked up the morning paper from the ground--
quotes: ['''"Of course, in your position of unofficial adviser and helper to everybody who is absolutely puzzled, throughout three continents, you are brought in contact with all that is strange and bizarre. But here"''', '''"let us put it to a practical test. Here is the first heading upon which I come. 'A husband's cruelty to his wife.' There is half a column of print, but I know without reading it that it is all perfectly familiar to me. There is, of course, the other woman, the drink, the push, the blow, the bruise, the sympathetic sister or landlady. The crudest of writers could invent nothing more crude."''']
section: "Of course, in your position of unofficial adviser and helper to everybody who is absolutely puzzled, throughout three continents, you are brought in contact with all that is strange and bizarre. But here"**--I picked up the morning paper from the ground--**"let us put it to a practical test. Here is the first heading upon which I come. 'A husband's cruelty to his wife.' There is half a column of print, but I know without reading it that it is all perfectly familiar to me. There is, of course, the other woman, the drink, the push, the blow, the bruise, the sympathetic sister or landlady. The crudest of writers could invent nothing more crude."
```

Comment: ```([^"]*"[^"]*")+``` should work (assuming you're starting outside of the quotes). ```[^"]*``` goes for the outside, ```"[^"]*"``` for the inside.

Comment: +1 showing us what you've tried and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple, the regular expression you need is `r'^("[^"]+")([^"]+)("[^"]+")'`:

```
import re

s = """
"I can quite understand your thinking so." I said. "Of course, in your position of unofficial adviser and helper to everybody who is absolutely puzzled, throughout three continents, you are brought in contact with all that is strange and bizarre. But here"

"Of course, in your position of unofficial adviser and helper to everybody who is absolutely puzzled, throughout three continents, you are brought in contact with all that is strange and bizarre. But here"--I picked up the morning paper from the ground--"let us put it to a practical test. Here is the first heading upon which I come. 'A husband's cruelty to his wife.' There is half a column of print, but I know without reading it that it is all perfectly familiar to me. There is, of course, the other woman, the drink, the push, the blow, the bruise, the sympathetic sister or landlady. The crudest of writers could invent nothing more crude."
"""

for segment in s.splitlines():
    if not segment:
        continue
    first, said, second = re.match(r'^("[^"]+")([^"]+)("[^"]+")', segment).groups()
    print first
    print said
    print second

>>> 
"I can quite understand your thinking so."
 I said. 
"Of course, in your position of unofficial adviser and helper to everybody who is absolutely puzzled, throughout three continents, you are brought in contact with all that is strange and bizarre. But here"
"Of course, in your position of unofficial adviser and helper to everybody who is absolutely puzzled, throughout three continents, you are brought in contact with all that is strange and bizarre. But here"
--I picked up the morning paper from the ground--
"let us put it to a practical test. Here is the first heading upon which I come. 'A husband's cruelty to his wife.' There is half a column of print, but I know without reading it that it is all perfectly familiar to me. There is, of course, the other woman, the drink, the push, the blow, the bruise, the sympathetic sister or landlady. The crudest of writers could invent nothing more crude."
```

Comment: thanks @Inbar, the regex works wonders. interestingly, have you tried on the regex on the data in the original post, i'm getting `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`

Comment: is it because the `^("[^"]+")` states that the quotes should be start of sentence? i do have some noise at the start of the sentence.

Comment: Then remove the first `^` which indicates the start of the string/line/match and instead of `re.match` use `re.search` . Next time you should include your actual data in its correct form that you want a solution for, else you will not get an answer the suits you.

Comment: why i can't match the group with `re.match` after removing the `^`?

Comment: Because `re.match` starts looking from the start of the string, while `re.search` will search in the string until it can start matching... Read the documentation next time.

Comment: ahh.. removing the `^` and using `re.search` works =) Thanks!!